# How to join rows in order without duplication

Tags: mysql

I have an history table that stores whenever a modem was activated or disactivated.
I want to join both rows: activation and deaactivation, in one.

I tryed with left join. But I get every actation row joined with every deaactivation row.

```
Activation
id_history  id_modem  date        Type
============================================
1           2         2017-07-14  Activation
3           2         2018-01-18  Activation


Deactivation
id_history  id_modem   date       Type
==============================================
2           2          2017-09-07 Deactivation
4           2          2018-02-19 Deactivation
```

I want to get this:

```
id_history_act  id_modem  date_act    type_act  id_history_dea  date_dea    type_dea
======================================================================================
1               2         2017-07-14  Act       2               2017-09-07  Dea
3               2         2018-01-18  Act       4               2018-02-19  Dea
```

But I am getting this when I make:

```
select 
    ha.id_history id_history_act,
    ha.id_modem,
    ha.date date_act,
    ha.type type_act,

    hd.id_history id_history_dea,
    hd.date date_dea,
    hd.type type_dea
from 
    history_activation ha 
    left join history_deactivation hd on(hd.id_modem = ha.id_modem);


id_history_act  id_modem  date_act    type_act  id_history_dea  date_dea    tupe_dea
==================================================================================
1               2         2017-07-14  Act       2               2017-09-07  Dea
1               2         2017-07-14  Act       4               2018-02-19  Dea
3               2         2018-01-18  Act       2               2017-09-07  Dea
3               2         2018-01-18  Act       4               2018-02-19  Dea
```

I tryed using a rank but I need to use variables and variables cannot be used in views.

And using count(*) with another join inside activation and deactivation queries is too slow.

Edit: This is the original table

```
HistoryTable
id_history  id_modem   date         Type 
====================================================
1           2          2017-07-14   Activation
2           2          2017-09-07   Deactivation
3           2          2018-01-18   Activation
4           2          2018-02-19   Deactivation
```

Comment: Append "ORDER BY date" after changing the synonyms date_act and date_des into "date". Also: it's 'deactivate' in English. ;)

Comment: This is not going to work until you either have a single table or otherwise relate these tables. For example, create activation and disactivation records  at same time supplying activation ID to disactivation table, leaving time NULL until disactivation occurs. How are you going to know, which activation relates to which disactivation?

Comment: Is activation and deactivation actually the same table? then how do you know which is which, only based that 1st is activate , next is disactivate?

Comment: Changed desactivation for deactivation. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: This is a data problem. You won't get the result you desire because they all have the same id_modem which is how you are mapping start and end dates.

Comment: Everything is in the same table. history_activation and history_deactivation  are separated queries of same table.

Comment: And how do you know, which record belongs to which event? your problem is DD. You need to have `id_history` and `activation_id` columns to relate your data as one of the options

Comment: If you are using one table, add one more column like deactivated and set it null. When a modem is activated add the record and when deactivated update the deactivated column.

Comment: I already know what records are activation and deactivation. That's why I put the activation and deactivation records separated directly in the example.
I just want to join the first activation with se first deactivation second with second and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ids and dates are consistent like  your sample data, then you need a self join and then select the minimum `id_history` and minimum `date` for `type = Deactivation` for each `type = Activation`:

```
select
  h1.id_history id_history_act, 
  h1.id_modem, 
  h1.date date_act,
  min(h2.id_history) id_history_des,
  min(h2.date) date_des
from HistoryTable h1 left join HistoryTable h2
on h2.id_modem = h1.id_modem and h2.date > h1.date
where h1.type = 'Activation' and h2.type = 'Deactivation'
group by h1.id_history, h1.id_modem, h1.date
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qYZHKkzqgwkGTjM5G4s9Yi/0).
Results:

```
| id_history_act | id_modem | date_act            | id_history_des | date_des            |
| -------------- | -------- | ------------------- | -------------- | ------------------- |
| 1              | 2        | 2017-07-14 00:00:00 | 2              | 2017-09-07 00:00:00 |
| 3              | 2        | 2018-01-18 12:03:14 | 4              | 2018-02-19 12:15:07 |
```

Comment: I think, this is same table and so far no way to distinct, which is which

Comment: There are 2 tables in the question.

Comment: See the comments please

Comment: Excellent! You are a genius! Thank you so much!

Comment: @YerryGarcía There is nothing genius here. Your original post did not have  `HistoryTable.Type` and was unsolvable without indicator of which record is which.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the ORDER BY clause in your query

try this:

```
select 
ha.id_history id_history_act,
ha.id_modem,
ha.date date_act,

hd.id_history id_history_des,
hd.date date_des,
from 
history_activation ha 
left join history_desctivation hd on(hd.id_modem = ha.id_modem);
order by date_act
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem here, unless this is I who does not

Comment: The problem is that I am getting 4 row instead of 2. I want to combine id 1 with id 2 and id 3 with id 4.

Comment: @YerryGarcía why id 1 with id 2? How do you know which is is for activation and which is for deactivation?

Comment: Because id 1 is when the modem was activated and id 2 is when modem was Deactivated after its last activation.